What are the types of merkle patricia nodes?
Another question related to a popular paper that always appears at the top of google search.
Related question:
To what extent has 2018 mLSM paper influenced ethereum data structure?
How is the following classification relevant today?

A merkle patricia trie in Ethereum consists of four types of nodes;
fullNode, which branches out into 17 child nodes (16 children one each for each character of hex and 1 child if there’s a value
terminating at that node); shortNode, an optimization which uses a
prefix as the key if there’s no branching at that prefix;
hashNode, which is used to convert a hash to a node doing a LevelDB lookup; valueNode, which is the leaf node which contains
the value stored for that key. Ethereum trie maintains both in-memory
trie and on-disk trie. On doing a commit, the in-memory trie is
committed to the disk by writing keyvalue pairs to LevelDB, by
introducing hash nodes.


The limitation of Patricia Trie were noted when looking for ways to scale the network. I'd guess that both Verkle and mLSM at some point were considered by the developers (both papers were published at 2018). Then Verkle was chosen as the solution to migrate the network https://vitalik.eth.limo/general/2021/06/18/verkle.html.
